# Different approaches to rigid-body movement

Tags: physics, rotation, movement, rigidbody, rigid-body-dynamics

I'm a beginner at game development and I'm building my own physics game engine to grasp the concepts.
I wonder if there are different approaches to moving and rotating a rigid body. For example, calculating the movement of each vertex vs center of mass (and what if it's outside the body?) vs edge movement.
I've tried to do some research online, however, I didn't find any useful information regarding this.

Comment: If it's a "rigid" body, then all vertices move together in perfect sync, no? What benefit would you gain from computing movement repeatedly for every vertex when they should all follow the same rigid transformation in each step?

Comment: That does seem unnecessary but I was just wondering if there are different methods, no matter their efficiency.

Comment: An exhaustive list of all possible ways to do a thing usually doesn't fit the Q&A format we use here very well. Have you encountered any specific problems with your center of mass based version that we could help you resolve?

Comment: Not really, but thank you!